# similar function for strcmpi in python

Tags: python, linux, string, ubuntu-10.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I do a case insensitive string comparison in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-python)

I wanted to know that if there is any function similar to `strcmpi` or some provision for it.

Suppose if user enters word `harry potter` and my file has this word written in this form `Harry Potter`, so how can I compare it because it simply ignores this because of the upper and lower case letters .

What if I want to convert an "instance" type object to str . How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way is to use `.lower()` on both strings and then just compare for equality:

```
>>> "Harry Potter".lower() == "harry potter".lower()
True
```

Answer (score 2):

You may convert both string to lower case before comparison:

```
a = "Harry Potter"
b = "harry potter"

print a.lower()==b.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [string.find](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.find)

```
string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])
```

To find all string ignoring the case:

```
str = "Hello! How are you?"
str.lower().find('hello'.lower())
```