# String comparison in Python that is case-insensitive for first letter

Tags: python, case-insensitive

I need to match the following string `File system full`. The problem is Starting F can be lowercase or capital. How can I do this in Python when string comparisons are usually case-sensitive?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I do a case insensitive string comparison in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-python)

Comment: What do you mean by "match"? Is there any `if` condition?

Comment: Hmm, why is it still open when there had been several questions like this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll be providing boolean indicators for you to play around with (rather than actual `if` blocks for the sake of conciseness.

Using Regex:

```
import re
bool(re.match('[F|f]',<your string>)) #if it matched, then it's true.  Else, false.
```

if the string could be anywhere in your output (I assume string)

```
import re
bool(re.search('[F|f]ile system full',<your string>))
```

Other options:

checking for 'f' and 'F'

```
<your string>[0] in ('f','F')

<your string>.startswith('f') or <your string>.startswith('F')
```

And there's the previously suggested `lower` method:

```
<your string>.lower() == 'f'
```

Comment: also `startswith(('f','F'))`

Answer (score 3):

You can [lower](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) your string before comparing it.

Answer (score 2):

```
test_string = "File system full"
if "file system full" == test_string.lower():
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = 'ABC'
>>> s.lower()
'abc'
>>>
```

After you could use any pattern for matching.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting string into any common(lower or upper) case and then compare

Answer (score 1):

```
if "File system full".lower() == test_string.lower():
    print True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
>>> import re
>>> bool(re.match('File system full','file system full', re.IGNORECASE))
True
```

For the more information, [re.IGNORECASE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function
Here,
Both the strings are converted to lowercase using `str.lower()` ,
If the first letter is the same in both strings,  it returns `True`
otherwise `False`

```
def match1(str1 ,str2):
    str1 = str1.lower() # to ignore the case
    str2 = str2.lower()
    if str1[0] == str2[0]:
        return True
    return False
```

Run on IDLE

```
>>> mystr = 'File system full'
>>> test1 = 'Flow'
>>> test2 = 'flower'
>>> match1(mystr,test1)
True
>>> match(mystr,test2)
True
```

I won't recommend using this technique as
You would need to have both lower and upper-case of the input string's letters
but it works :)

```
def match2(str1 ,str2):
    if str2[0] == str1[0].lower()\
    or str2[0] == str1[0].upper():
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do in the below way:

```
st="File system full"       
vl = re.search(r"(?i)File system full", st)
```

`(?i)` matches both uppercase and lower case letters.

Comment: @Sandeep Krishnan You can also implement in the way which i have added. when you get a chance please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This solutions works well for all possible case Patterns

```
string = "true" 
boolean = eval(string.capitalize())
print(boolean)
```