# case insensitive and while giving input of age as 31 it shows error: TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand

Tags: python

My abc txt file looks like this:

```
Nathan  Johnson 23 M
Mary    Kom     28 F
John    Keyman  32 M
Edward  Stella  35 M
```

Now when i Search a string within a file let say i search for Mary and  I give input search as "mary" , then no data found . i.e. case insensitive. how do i do that ? also
when i take Age as 31 which i m coverting to integer it gives me error

```
#!usr/bin/python
import sys

class Person:

    def __init__(self, firstname=None, lastname=None, age=None, gender=None):

        self.fname = firstname
        self.lname = lastname
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

    def searchFName(self, matchString):
        return matchString in self.fname

    def searchLName(self, matchString):
        return matchString in self.lname

    def searchAge(self, matchString):      
        return matchString in self.age

    def searchGender(self, matchString):        
       return matchString in self.gender

   def display(self):
       print self.fname, self.lname, self.age, self.gender


f= open("abc","r")
list_of_records = [Person(*line.split()) for line in f]

found = False
n=0

n1 = raw_input("Enter for Search Criteria\n1.FirstName  2.LastName  3.Age  4.Gender      5.Exit " )

if n1.isdigit():
    n = int(n1)
else:
    print "Enter Integer from given"
    sys.exit(1)
if n == 0 or n>5:
    print "Enter valid search "

if n == 1:
    StringSearch = raw_input("Enter FirstName :")
        for records in list_of_records:
        if (records.searchFName(StringSearch)):
            found = True
            records.display()

    if not found:
        print "No matched record"

if n == 2:
    StringSearch = raw_input("Enter LastName :")
    for records in list_of_records:
        if records.searchLName(StringSearch):
            found = True
            records.display()

    if not found:
        print "No matched record"

if n == 3:
    StringSearch = int(raw_input("Enter Age :"))
    if StringSearch > 100:
        print "Please enter valid age"

    for records in list_of_records:
        if records.searchAge(StringSearch):
            found = True
            records.display()

    if not found:
        print "No matched record"

if n == 4:
    StringSearch = raw_input("Enter Gender(M/F) :")
    for records in list_of_records:
        if records.searchGender(StringSearch):
            found = True
            records.display()

    if not found:
        print "No matched record"

if n == 5:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Error :

```
Enter for Search Criteria
1.FirstName  2.LastName  3.Age  4.Gender  5.Exit 3
Enter Age :41
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestObjectSearch.py", line 143, in <module>
    if records.searchAge(StringSearch):
  File "TestObjectSearch.py", line 77, in searchAge
    return matchString in self.age
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand
```

Comment: Please show exactly what the error is, including the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep age as an integer, you'll need to change your **init**() method and your searchAge() method in the Person class like this:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, firstname=None, lastname=None, age=None, gender=None):
    ...
    self.age = int(age) # Convert from string to int

    ...

    def searchAge(self, matchString):      
        return matchString == self.age # Check int against int
```

And in order to do a case-insensitive search, you do this:

```
def searchFName(self, matchString):
    return matchString.lower() in self.fname.lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

If matchString needs to be an int, you could do:

```
def searchAge(self, matchString):      
    return str(matchString) in self.age
```

or convert age to an int in the constructor and keep the code as it is.

Also, in your code this part looks wrong:

```
StringSearch = int(raw_input("Enter Age :"))
for records in list_of_records:
if records.searchGender(StringSearch):
    found = True
    records.display()
```

You are asking for an age, but you invoke .searchGender()

Comment: how about the case insensitive ?

Comment: You can transform the strings to lower case, e.g., return matchString.lower() in self.fname.lower()

Comment: @Johnjohn There's this search engine, that if you type "python case insensitive" (it even auto completes a lot of that for you so you don't even have to do insensitive right...)... you get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-python/ as the top link. I mention this as the questions you've been asking, were one to copy and paste the error message received, you'd have already found existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

For any case-insensitive search, make both the strings in to comparable same case(but preserve the original string case)

```
st = "aAbBLKJkjdsJKJKJKfdfs"
to_find = "aabb"

if to_find.lower() in st.lower():
    print "String Found"
```

Here,

```
to_find.lower() and st.lower()
```

will not alter the original string

Answer (score 0):

The error seems clear: `matchString in self.age` requires `matchString` to be a string. But when searching age, you explicitly convert the input to an integer. If you want to use it to search a string, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: I want to make an integer and search that. if I dont covert age  into integer its working fine but i want to take it as an integer

Comment: You can't use an integer to search a string. If you want to make the search value an integer, then the thing you're comparing against must also be an integer. In which case you won't be able to do an `in` search, but just a strict comparison.

Comment: what should i do than ??