# Comparing a string to a list of characters

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

Say I have a list of characters `['h','e','l','l','o']` and I wanted to see if the list of characters match a string `'hello'`, how would I do this? The list needs to match the characters exactly. I thought about using something like:

```
hList = ['h','e','l','l','o']
hStr = "Hello"
running = False

if hList in hStr :
  running = True
  print("This matches!")
```

but this does not work, how would I do something like this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `''.join(hList) == hStr`.

That turns the list into a string, so it can be easily compared to the other string.

In your case you don't seem to care about case, so you can use a case insensitive compare. See [How do I do a case insensitive string comparison in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-python) for a discussion of this.

Comment: ah thanks, it seems obvious now as ' '.join(hList) converts the list to a string :P

Answer (score 1):

Or, another way is the reverse of what the other answer suggests, create a list out of `hStr` and compare that:

```
list(hStr) == hList
```

Which simply compares the lists:

```
list('Hello') == hList
False

list('hello') == hList
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is to split the string into array:

```
list(hStr) == hList  


>>> list("hello")
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```