# Comparing string regardless of lowercase and uppercase characters in python

Tags: string, python-2.7, compare

Is there a way to compare between strings so that uppercase and lowercase letters will be considered as the same letter?

For example, that `'ABC' == 'abc` will result `true`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution would be to convert both values to lower or upper case and make comparison if the are equal.

```
string1, string2 = "ABC", "abc"

string1.lower() == string2.lower()
```