# Python how to search a list for all permutatio of a given input?

Tags: python

So basically my question is this. Let's say I have a list with values

```
l1st = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'monkey']
```

And I ask the user to input

```
input = raw_input('Please enter the word you wish to search for: ')
```

Here's the big question. Let's say the person wants to search for

```
dog
```

but types it in as

```
Dog
```

I don't want the program to give him an error message just because he got the capitalization wrong. What is a method I could use for a list.index search to look for, if not the exact word, the closest similar word?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the strings by turning both into their lower case form. Here's the [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_lower.htm). Just as you're doing the search use:

```
if input.lower() == item.lower():
    do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .lower() method to take the input and create the lower case version. You can also look at this link https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches which will get closest match to a word froma. List. Hope this helps