# Python 3.x is this the fastest way to compare strings? case insensitive string comparison

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, comparison, case

Is there some module out there that has fast case insensitive string comparisons for Python 3.x or is this the fastest way to compare A LOT of strings?

```
def compare(s1,s2):
    if s1.upper() == s2.upper():
        return True
    return False

print (compare("59gndif_^ngJJDS","59gndif_^ngJJDS"))
print (compare("59gndifngJJDS","insdffn"))

True
False
```

Comment: in order to have cleaner code, you could just return 's1.upper() == s2.upper()'

Comment: Note  that comparing `.upper()` actually is not always correct. There are special characters in some languages that have no uppercase, like the *est-zet* in German.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem would .lower() work in those situations?

Comment: surprisingly I couldn't (easily) find an original question to make that one a duplicate, so +1 :)

Comment: @new_to_coding: I seriously doubt that. Some see the est-zet as a typography trick (which is almost certainly its orginin). Usually in german the upper-case variant of *est-zet* is `'SS'` or `'SZ'`, so making that `lower()` again will result in `'sz'`...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: perhaps [this is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551443/67579).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem clearly it is!! I've edited to add the "python" tag so you can close that!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that's it! work as a team :) note that the old question can still be answered if someone figures out the fastest way to compare strings.