# Sort string array first on length then alphabetically in Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting

How to sort an array in python firstly by the length of the words (longest to shortest), and then alphabetically?

Here is what I mean:

I have this list: `WordsArray = ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", "tempor", "incididunt"]`

I want to output this: `['consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'incididunt', 'eiusmod', 'tempor', 'dolor', 'ipsum', 'Lorem', 'amet', 'elit', 'sed', 'sit', 'do']`

I can already sort alphabetically using `print (sorted(WordsArray))`:

```
['Lorem', 'adipiscing', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'do', 'dolor', 'eiusmod', 'elit', 'incididunt', 'ipsum', 'sed', 'sit', 'tempor']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, using **just** `sorted` will **not sort alphabetically**, look at your output... I am pretty sure `L` does not come before `a`. What you are currently doing is a **case-sensitive** sort.

You can perform a **case-insensitive** sort by using a [**Key Function**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions) like so:

```
>>> words_list = ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", "tempor", "incididunt"]
>>> sorted(words_list, key=str.lower)
['adipiscing', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'do', 'dolor', 'eiusmod', 'elit', 'incididunt', 'ipsum', 'Lorem', 'sed', 'sit', 'tempor']
```

You can then modify the [**Key Function**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions) like below to sort first on length then alphabetically:

```
>>> def custom_key(str):
...   return -len(str), str.lower()
... 
>>> sorted(words_list, key=custom_key)
['consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'incididunt', 'eiusmod', 'tempor', 'dolor', 'ipsum', 'Lorem', 'amet', 'elit', 'sed', 'sit', 'do']
```

Comment: Solution works, but have a doubt. With `lower`, the order comes in : `..'dolor', 'ipsum'..` , but without it, the order is `..'ipsum', 'dolor'..` How can `lower` make a difference there?

Comment: @KaushikNP Sorry I don't understand? if you look at OP's code `dolor` is before `ipsum` and it is also before in both of my examples?

Comment: As i said, Your solution works. Trying some variations on my own, I noticed that behaviour.

Comment: `>>>  sorted(words_list, key=lambda x: (-len(x)))` gives 
`=> ['consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'incididunt', 'eiusmod', 'tempor', 'Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'amet', 'elit', 'sit', 'sed', 'do']`

Comment: @KaushikNP You mean when you don't sort alphabetically, it doesn't get sorted alphabetically? Shocking.

Answer (score 4):

You can use as key a tuple that specifies first the negative length of the string `-len(x)` and then `x` itself:

```
sorted(WordsArray, key=lambda x: (-len(x),x))
```

Since tuples are sorted by the first element and in case of *ex aequo* by the second element and so on, we thus first compare on the `-len(x)` of the two strings, so that means that the larger string is sorted first.

In case both strings have the same length, we compare on `x`, so alphabetically.

Mind that sorting two strings is *case sensitive*: Python sorts them lexicographically, but where the order is specified by the `ord(..)` of the first characters, etc. If you want to order alphabetically, you better convert upper case and lower case to the same case. A fast way to handle this is:

```
sorted(WordsArray, key=lambda x: (-len(x),x.lower()))
```

But this is **not always correct**: since for instance the est-zet in German is sometimes translate to `ss`, etc. In fact sorting alphabetically is a very hard problem in some languages. So in that case, you need to specify **collation**.

Comment: Solution works, but have a doubt. With `lower`, the order comes in : `..'dolor', 'ipsum'..` , but without it, the order is `..'ipsum', 'dolor'..` How can `lower` make a difference there?

Comment: @KaushikNP: because not all characters have a `lower` in all cultures/languages. It is already a hard problem whether two strings are equivalent. In German for instance `'Foostraße'` en `'Foostrasse'` are frequently seen as the *same* text. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29247821/67579) for instance.

Comment: what you say are correct. I don't think you understand my problem though. `>>>  sorted(words_list, key=lambda x: (-len(x)))` gives 
`=> ['consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'incididunt', 'eiusmod', 'tempor', 'Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'amet', 'elit', 'sit', 'sed', 'do']`  . Order should not be so for `ipsum` and `dolor` though.

Comment: @KaushikNP: yes, but that's why we map `x` to a 2-tuple: `(-len(x),x.lower())` (so in case the two `-len(x)`s are equal, Python will perform a comparison on the second element of the tuple `x.lower()`.

Comment: Oh, ok. Otherwise there is no comparision? Hmmm. Got it

Answer (score 0):

For who in my case:

> A = [a_12,a_3,a_11]

sorted(A, key=lambda x: (len(x),x))

> [a_3, a_11, a_12]