# How to make a search function case in-sensitive | Python

Tags: python, case-insensitive

**Intro**: I have been continuing to follow a textbook on programming (Python, specifically), with the latest 'problem' to solve,  being the creation of a 'Phone Number Look-up'.

**The brief:** The textbook asks the user to create two parallel arrays (7 friend's names & phone numbers) and a search function that steps through the people array and returns both that search result (based on user input) of the friend(s) name(s) and corresponding phone number (note: names and corresponding phone numbers are using identical index positions.

**The issue:** I have `def` a `arraysAndSearch` module (that has my `people` and `phoneNumbers` `array`) and used `enumerate()` for ease of looping over the `people` array and inc. an automatic counter. The program is working, as it's returning full and partial matches of both the person and corresponding index id in the `phoneNumbers` array, **however** I **have had** **issues trying to adapt my code, so that case in-sensitivty is observed.**

E.g. searching for 'Katie' returns the two expected values from the `people` array and corresponding index id from `phoneNumbers`. Searching for 'katie', returns no results, I simply get my error message, that is coded to appear `if not arraySearch:`.

**Code Extract:**

```
def arraysAndSearch(nameSearch):
    people = ['Silviu Ciocanel', 'Katie Trolan', 'Katie MacPherson']
    phoneNumbers = ['310-443-7798', '562-905-3343', '310-983-5209']
    arraySearch = [people for people in enumerate(people) if nameSearch in people[1]]
    for index, nameSearch in arraySearch:
        print("Name: ", nameSearch, "\nPhone:", phoneNumbers[index])
    if not arraySearch:
        print("No matches in phone book :(")
    print("****************************")
```

Is anyone able to offer some guidance as to how I can integrate case in-sensitivity?

Comment: "The textbook asks the user to create two parallel arrays" Wow, I hope there is more context to this or else it is horrible advice. The data structure of choice should be a dictionary where the keys are lower-case names and the values are the phone numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to achieve this is to ensure that both the input and the search string are in the same case (e.g. both are lowercase):

```
arraySearch = [people for people in enumerate(people) if nameSearch.lower() in people[1].lower()]
```

Comment: This really helped, thank you. I did try `lower()` however failed to 'bolt it' onto `nameSearch` AND `people`. A lesson learnt in attention to detail.