# Accepting multiple answers as an 'if' variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I accept multiple options/answers for an input. For example:

```
if player_ship == 'Transport' or 'TRANSPORT' or 'transport':
        print('You successfully purchased a Transport Ship!\n\n')
```

Comment: Plus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will ensure that case sensitivity is not a problem.

```
if player_ship.lower() == 'transport'
```

If you genuinely need to check against specific values, this will work:

```
if player_ship in {'Transport', 'TRANSPORT', 'transport'}
```