# How to filter a Pandas dataframe in python based on column value comparison?

Tags: python, pandas

If you have a Pandas dataframe like this, filtering this way works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name1': ['apple','pear','applepie','APPLE'],
                'name2': ['APPLE','PEAR','apple','APPLE']
            })
df[df['name1'] != df['name2']] # works
```

But how do you filter rows, when you want to compare the upper values of the columns?

```
df[df['name1'].upper() != df['name2'].upper()]  # does not work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`pandas.Series.str.upper()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.upper.html) as `df['name1']` is a series of strings and hence we use [`.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) string accessor for vectorized string manipulation.

```
df[df['name1'].str.upper() != df['name2'].str.upper()]
```

Output:

```
       name1    name2
2   applepie    apple
```

Answer (score 1):

Often times it can be faster to use list comprehensions when dealing with strings in pandas.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [[i, j] for i, j in zip(df.name1, df.name2) if i.upper() != j.upper()],
    columns=df.columns
)

      name1  name2
0  applepie  apple
```

Some timings:

```
In [159]: df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

In [160]: %%timeit
     ...:     pd.DataFrame(
     ...:         [[i, j] for i, j in zip(df.name1, df.name2) if i.upper() != j.upper()]
     ...: ,
     ...:         columns=df.columns
     ...:     )
     ...:
14.2 ms ± 68.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [161]: %timeit df[df['name1'].str.upper() != df['name2'].str.upper()]
35.6 ms ± 160 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

*For ASCII-only, check above :)*

Just as an observation, following *[this very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29247821/2535611)* from @Veedrac, if you want to compare case-insensitive for lots of rows in many languages, you might want to `normalize` and `casefold` the values first

```
df.col.str.normalize('NFKD').transform(str.casefold)
```

*Example*

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'t':['a','b','A', 'ê', 'ê', 'Ê', 'ß', 'ss']})

df.t.duplicated()
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
```

and

```
df.t.str.lower().duplicated()
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
```

But

```
df.t.str.normalize('NFKD').transform(str.casefold).duplicated(keep=False)

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
```