# Python string search case insensitive

Tags: python, string

I am trying to have a program react dependent on what the user types but i do not want it to be case sensitive e.g.

```
MenuOption = input("Login or Register or Press 'Q' to quit")
while MenuOption != "login" and MenuOption != "register" and MenuOption!= "q":
    print("Please enter one of the two options")
    MenuOption = input("Login or Register")
```

the program only allows you access if you type in lowecase but I do not want the case of the letters to affect it at all so you could type in "lOgIN" and it would still read that as login.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Comment: I had a look but by the sounds of things that is comparing two strings together. I did have a look maybe i am missing something

Comment: found it i was mistaken, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.lower()` method, e.g. `MenuOption.lower()`.  This will convert the input string to all lowercase letters.

Comment: sorted thank you so much i was using it just on the while loop but just changed it for the others so thank you friend

Comment: @TryDodgingThis: If it solved your problem, please accept the answer