# .str.contains is not detecting some rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm using `df.str.contains` to find the "@company" substring in a particular column and drop all that don't match.

I've done it manually to compare and I should be getting over 100 results, but I get only 55 running the script.

`DF = DF[DF['Email '].astype(str).str.contains('@company', regex=False)]`

I'm using `regex=False` to prevent `.str.contains` from thinking the @ sign is a Regex

UPDATE:

I solved the issue by moving this part of the program above others, as other "filters" and "drops" were removing rows before the email could be read. Thanks for your input!

Comment: This `"@company"` is not the same as this `"@COMPANY"`

Comment: If you need to capture both uppercase and lowercase of `@company` you can just make all of it lowercase and search only the lowercase version:
`DF = DF[DF['Email '].astype(str).str.lower().contains('@COMPANY', regex=False)]`

Comment: Sorry, just a typo while writing the question. I'll edit it.

Comment: you can pass `case=False` as well to ignore case, or as linamnt has done by using `.str.lower()` let us know if you need anymore help

Comment: I think there must be something strange about the dataframe, or specifically those lines not getting detected, that we cannot know without seeing the data

Comment: I passed `case=False` in hopes it was something like that, still not working. How could I share the dataset with you?

Comment: If @DanielMesejo is right, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison

Comment: @LoneWanderer Yeah, it's all email addresses. Unfortunately the data is sensitive for the company I work for and I can't share it without "cleaning it", or it might cost me my job.

I think that changing anything to later share it with you will actually serve no purpose if the errors are in the data itself as linamnt suggested

Comment: Forgive me, but then, your whole question is pointless, isn't it ? (BTW, I did not notice the 'Email' column at first... what a genius ! too focused on the '@company')

Comment: @LoneWanderer haha, no worries. I solved the issue by moving this part of the program above others, as other "filters" and "drops" were removing rows before the email could be read. Thanks for your input!