# how to make a value true or false with an input?

Tags: python, input

I know I should probably be able to figure this out on my own, but how do I simply make a code that changes somethings value depending on the input. This is my code:

```
a = False
c = input("do you want A to be positive or negative?\n")

if c== "Pos" or "pos":
    print("a switched to positive")
    a = True

if c== "Neg" or "neg":
    print("a switched to negative")
    a = False
```

It doesn't work though. How would I do this? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison

Answer (score 0):

Your python syntax is wrong. When checking in if condition, instead of

```
if c == "Pos" or "pos"
```

You should have,

```
if c == "Pos" or c == "pos"
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution:

```
a = False
c = input("do you want A to be positive or negative?\n")

if "pos" in c.lower():
    print("a switched to positive")
    a = True
elif "neg" in c.lower():
    print("a switched to negative")
    a = False
```

This will allow user to type "positive" or "negative" both in lower and caps. Also just "pos" and "neg" will be okay.