# Python 3 weird len function behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, uppercase

I have the following code

```
for i in range(500):
 if(len(chr(i).upper())==2):
  print(chr(i))
```

surprisingly this print some characters on the screen, while this code does not

```
for i in range(500):
 if(len(chr(i))==2):
  print(chr(i))
```

why is some character when pass through the method upper, yields length of two ? I heard it's related to buffer and unicode (?) I still don't know.

Comment: Try adding `print(i, chr(i), chr(i).upper())` to your loop and you will see... The upper of `ß` is `SS` for example

Comment: can you explain the reason behinds that?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `len`, that's just what you're using. IMO a better title would be "Why do some characters turn into two characters when I change their case?"

Comment: Related: [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/319426/4518341)

Comment: Here's a good example: U+64256 is a ligature, `ﬀ`, which uppercases to `FF`.

Comment: @wjandrea good example, except it's not within the range being tested here.

Comment: @SumantoDinar what do you mean explain the reason? That's just what those characters are. Their length is 2, there is nothing weird going on, especially not with `len`...

Comment: the reason behind why the upper of ß is SS.

Comment: "the reason behind why the upper of ß is SS" has nothing to do with programming, it has to do with the German language.