# List for loop continues if user inputs anything

Tags: python

When I input text for my verdict I can put anything, e.g. "zzzzz", and the program continues on through the list.

I want the program to stop when user inputs "Guilty". And only move on when user inputs "Not Guilty".

This is what I have so far, I also tried using `while True` if that's better?

```
guilty = False
character = ["Miss Scarlett", "Professor Plum", "Mrs Peacock", "Reverend Green", "Colonel Mustard", "Dr Orchid"]

while not guilty:
    for accused in character:
        verdict = input("Do you find %s guilty or not guilty? " % accused)
        if verdict == "guilty":
            print("User finds %s guilty" % accused)
            guilty = True
            break
        else:
            guilty = False
```

Comment: it is case sensitive, so it might be a good idea to use `verdict.lower()` where you're doing the if comparison, other than that it looks like it's fitting your needs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Comment: Just to make it more explicit: string comparisons in Python are case sensitive, so `verdict == "guilty"` and `verdict == "Guilty"` are different statements and will only match strings that have the exact same case. Using something like `verdict.lower() == "guilty"` will transform the user input to lower case and, only then, compare it -- this will make your program work regardless of whether the user wrote `guilty`, `Guilty`, or `gUiLtY`.

Comment: thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accept only answers `guilty` and `not guilty` you can remove the top `while` loop and move it inside for-loop. Also, use `str.lower` to make answers case-insensitive:

```
character = ["Miss Scarlett", "Professor Plum", "Mrs Peacock", "Reverend Green", "Colonel Mustard", "Dr Orchid"]

for accused in character:
    verdict = ''
    while verdict not in ('guilty', 'not guilty'):
        verdict = input("Do you find %s guilty or not guilty? " % accused).lower()

    if verdict == "guilty":
        print("User finds %s guilty" % accused)
        break
```

Prints (for example):

```
Do you find Miss Scarlett guilty or not guilty? d
Do you find Miss Scarlett guilty or not guilty? d
Do you find Miss Scarlett guilty or not guilty? f
Do you find Miss Scarlett guilty or not guilty? not guilty
Do you find Professor Plum guilty or not guilty? guilty
User finds Professor Plum guilty
```