# How to search OpenStack users case insensitive?

Tags: python, openstack

I have an OpenStack cloud connected to LDAP (of which I have no control and doesn't return the matching case when I query) where Keystone has the user as 'UserNaMe' and if I search for a user with this code, the id is returned:

```
conn = openstack.connect(cloud)
pprint(conn.identity.find_user('UserNaMe'))
```

However, if I search for a username without the proper case, no id is returned:

```
pprint(conn.identity.find_user('username'))
```

Since the https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/proxies/identity_v3.html#user-operations documentation is not specific, how do I make the search case insensitive so that I always get the correct user id?

Horizon seems to have no issue with 'username' instead of 'UserNaMe', so there must be a way to search insensitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to inspect the [Horizon source](https://github.com/openstack/horizon) and see how it handles the user search.

Another option would be to iterate over the list of users and perform case-insensitive comparisons. E.g.:

```
want_user = 'UserNaMe'

found_user = [user for user in conn.identity.users()
              if user.name.lower() == want_user.lower()]
```

Comment: While not the ideal solution, this works around the issue well enough to unblock. A slight improvement would be to use casefold() instead of lower() for reasons shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison question. Since the find_user function returns the id of the user, it would not be difficult to modify this sample code to do similar.