# comparing two string lists regardless of order and case in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have below code:

```
old_sqls = ["select * from T1", "select * from T2", "select * from T3"]
new_sql = ["SELECT * FROM T1", "SELECT * FROM T3", "SELECT * FROM T2"]

if old_sqls == new_sql:
    print("equals")
else:
    print("not equals")
```

its giving `not equals` I want result of this to `equals`. looking to ignore both order and case of strings used in list. Compare them regardless or order and case in one statement and print `equals`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare general strings, to avoid issues with unicode, I suggest you [normalize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) the strings and use [casefold](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold):

```
import unicodedata


def normalize_caseless(text):
    return unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", text.casefold())


old_sql = ["select * from T1", "select * from T2", "select * from T3"]
new_sql = ["SELECT * FROM T1", "SELECT * FROM T3", "SELECT * FROM T2"]

if set(map(normalize_caseless, old_sql)) == set(map(normalize_caseless, new_sql)):
    print("equals")
else:
    print("not equals")
```

**Output**

```
equals
```

You can see why this is useful, in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29247821/4001592).

Also note that you could use a set, which makes the comparison *O(n)* (expected), although with larger constants. So this should be faster that *O(nlogn)* for larger lists.

Set will only work if there are not duplicates strings, for that case you could use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import unicodedata
from collections import Counter

def normalize_caseless(text):
    return unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", text.casefold())


old_sql = ["select * from T1", "select * from T2", "select * from T3"]
new_sql = ["SELECT * FROM T1", "SELECT * FROM T3", "SELECT * FROM T2"]

if Counter(map(normalize_caseless, old_sql)) == Counter(map(normalize_caseless, new_sql)):
    print("equals")
else:
    print("not equals")
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a good candidate for the use of Python sets.

```
old_sqls=["select * from T1","select * from T2","select * from T3"]
new_sql=["SELECT * FROM T1","SELECT * FROM T3","SELECT * FROM T2"]

if {e.upper() for e in old_sqls} == {e.upper() for e in new_sql}:
    print("equals")
else:
    print("not equals")
```

*Note: This method only works if it doesn't matter how many times a list element occurs. See other answers' use of Python `Counter` objects if frequency is relevant. Thanks to Costaparas for pointing this out.*

Comment: This is a very neat solution, but the caveat here is it doesn't consider the frequency of the list elements. Comparing lists and sets is not the same thing -- since elements of a list can be repeated and that would make them *different* whereas as sets, they'd be considered equal (of course it might not matter depending on the usage so this answer still has a lot of merit).

Answer (score 2):

Lower-casing and sorting is fine but sorting is log-linear. A linear approach would be counting and can be applied using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
 from collections import Counter

 if Counter(map(str.lower, old_sql)) == Counter(map(str.lower, new_sql)):
     # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sorted`:

```
old_sqls = ["select * from T1", "select * from T2", "select * from T3"]
new_sql = ["SELECT * FROM T1", "SELECT * FROM T3", "SELECT * FROM T2"]

if sorted([i.lower() for i in old_sqls]) == sorted([i.lower() for i in new_sql]):
    print("equals")
else:
    print("not equals")
```

`sorted` sorts lists, so here I sort both lists, so the order should be the same if the two lists have the same values.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I used sorted and it works but want to consider case as well.

Comment: @schwobaseggl You can post as an answer :-)

Comment: Glad you thought better and deleted your last comment. Please remember not to hareass people to accept your answer, it's only been 5 minutes for crying out loud.

Comment: @cs95 So sorry for that, shouldn't of posted that comment