# Make if statment not care about capitalisation

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make if comparisons not care about the capitals.

I have tried to Google this but nothing shows up with the answer im looking for.

Example Code:

```
word = input()
if word == 'banana':
    print("Apples")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do:

```
word = input()
if word.lower() == 'banana':
    print("Apples")
```

Also recommend: [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in `lower()` function like this:

```
word = input()
if word.lower() == 'banana':
    print("Apples")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could transform `input` to lowercase like this:

```py
word = input()
if word.lower() == 'banana':
    print("Apples")
```