# How do i make a discord bot not case-sensitive? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

How do i make a discord bot not case sensitive? The method I'm currently using isn't working. I’ve seen other quest like this but they aren't related to what I’m doing.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', case_insensitive=True) #ive tried both true/false. neither works 

print("Starting...")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Logged on as {0.user}".format(bot))

  @bot.event
  async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
      return

    elif 'hello' in message.content:
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(‘hi')
bot.run("Token")
```

I want the user to be able to say either Hello or hello and it will work. Any ideas on how i would go about that?

Comment: `elif 'hello' in message.content.lower():`  To make a comparison case-sensitive, just force the two strings you're comparing to be lowercase (or uppercase, as long as you use the same case for both strings).

Comment: Where is your `@bot.command` that you want to be case-insensitive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Comment: I’m not using commands I’m just detecting if messages are sent

Comment: Could you write that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly new to this myself so the method I know is you can use .lowercase() when comparing. What this will do is it'll convert the whole string to lowercase, it doesn't matter if the user wrote "Hello", "hello" , "HEllO", etc. All these strings would be converted to "hello" when .lowercase() is used.

This is my first answer so hope I was able to explain it properly. Attaching the code for your reference.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', case_insensitive=True) #ive tried both true/false. neither works 

print("Starting...")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Logged on as {0.user}".format(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    elif 'hello' in message.content.lower():
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(‘hi')

bot.run("Token")
```

Let me know if it works!!