# Filter a dictionary based on a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with values in CamelCase sensitive and I'd like to filter the dictionary values based on a list of lower case elements:

```
d = {'1a': ['DW_TEST (DEV)', 'public', 'Labs'],
     '1b': ['DW_TEST (DEV)', 'public', 'Test'],
     '1c': ['DW_TEST (PROD)', 'public', 'Labs'],
     '1d': ['DW_TEST (PROD)', 'public', 'Test'],
     '2a': ['DW_PROD (PROD)', 'public', 'Medications'],
     '2b': ['DW_PROD (DEV)', 'public', 'Med_Test']}

l = [['dw_test (dev)', 'public', 'labs'],
     ['dw_test (prod)', 'public', 'labs'],
     ['dw_prod (prod)', 'public', 'medications']]
```

Expected dictionary:

```
d = {'1a': ['DW_TEST (DEV)', 'public', 'Labs'],
         '1c': ['DW_TEST (PROD)', 'public', 'Labs'],
         '2a': ['DW_PROD (PROD)', 'public', 'Medications']}
```

I know how to filter based on dictionary keys but I'd like to filter dictionary values based on a list.

Comment: Is your problem how to compare two strings in a case-insensitive way?

Comment: This `['dw_test (prod)', 'public', 'medications']` is not present the values of the dictionary

Comment: More or less the same @mkrieger1

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison for that.

Comment: My bad. See the updated one @DaniMesejo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to convert l into a set of tuples (lookup) and then filter out those items which value is not present in the set:

```
lookup = set(tuple(li) for li in l)
result = {key: value for key, value in d.items() if tuple(map(str.lower, value)) in lookup}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'1a': ['DW_TEST (DEV)', 'public', 'Labs'], '1c': ['DW_TEST (PROD)', 'public', 'Labs'], '2a': ['DW_PROD (PROD)', 'public', 'Medications']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by passing through string comparison like this :

```
l = [str(i) for i in l]
new_dict = {key:value for (key,value) in d.items() if str(value).lower() in l}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'1a': ['DW_TEST (DEV)', 'public', 'Labs'],
     '1b': ['DW_TEST (DEV)', 'public', 'Test'],
     '1c': ['DW_TEST (PROD)', 'public', 'Labs'],
     '1d': ['DW_TEST (PROD)', 'public', 'Test'],
     '2a': ['DW_PROD (PROD)', 'public', 'Medications'],
     '2b': ['DW_PROD (DEV)', 'public', 'Med_Test']}

l = [['dw_test (dev)', 'public', 'labs'],
     ['dw_test (prod)', 'public', 'labs'],
     ['dw_test (prod)', 'public', 'medications']]

d_l = { k:[ii.lower() for ii in i] for k,i in d.items() }
l_l = [[ii.lower() for ii in i] for i in l]
o = {}
for key, value in d_l.items():
    for item in l_l:
        if item == value:
            o[key] = d[key]
print(o)
```

This should work, converting both lists/dict into lower case, comparing and then appending from the original list