# Loosen up search

Tags: python, if-statement

so how can I make Hello and hELLO the same.

```
s = "Hello this is me"
if "HEllo" in s:
    print("Hello in s")
```

It will not print Hello in s, how can I make it the same if its written big or small? Its basically the same. Maybe it should look not for the exatc same but for the same spelling?
Please help (also I'm not american sorry for the text)

Comment: `str.lower` or `upper` both before the comparison.

Comment: use ```casefold()```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/319426/1639625 (using `==`, but works just as well for `in`)

Answer (score 1):

You can lowercase everything using str.lower so it will look like:

```
s = "Hello this is me"
if "HEllo".lower() in s.lower():
    print("Hello in s")
```