# My Python list doesn't understand letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code doesn't understand letters in the list. How can i fix this?

```
usernames = (BTP, btp, Btp, BTp)
def username(usernames2):
    if usernames == input('whats your username? : ')
```

It's a simple username system, I plan to use for a interface I'm making.

Comment: *usernames* is not a list - it's a tuple. Presumably BTP, btp, Btp & BTp are declared elsewhere in your code. Input returns a string and therefore will never be equal to a tuple. I recommend https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Comment: I dont even know where to start

Comment: This question is hard to understand.  You need to think more about what you're asking and include that in your question along with what you get when you run this code and what you expect.

Several problems in your code - the username function takes a usernames2 argument but the function uses usernames, you are comparing the usernames tuple to the result of input rather than checking if input is in tuple, etc.

Comment: No it is not also this is the Full code

Comment: Do you mean that python doesn't understand that when you type `BTP` you really meant to type `'BTP'`? In any event, letters are strings, and Python understands them perfectly well. You just need to use the right syntax when working with them.

Comment: I'm asking how do i make my list At the beginning of the code understand words as of my knowledge it can only understand numbers

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you mean usernames = ('BTP', 'btp', 'Btp', 'BTp')

Comment: I am sorry I'm stupid and forgot to add the ''

Comment: it wont let me delete :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't declared `BTP`, `btp`, `Btp`, and `BTp` you will get a `NameError`

If you wanted to use strings you need single or double quotation marks:

```py
usernames = ("BTP", "btp", "Btp", "BTp")
```

With that you create a **tuple** containing four string elements.

The next issue is with your `if` condition as you compare if a `tuple` is equal a string.

Try storing the input given from the user in a variable:

```py
def username(usernames):
    user_input = input('whats your username?: ')
    if user_input in usernames:
        # Do something when username is found
```

Comment: When I do this The input does not do anything, therefore the code does nothing.

Comment: Of course it does nothing as you need to add your code inside the `if` block where I just put a comment.

Comment: But i don't even get asked for a input

Comment: That is because with this you only define the function. In order to use the function you need to call the function.

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: You call functions by their name plus parentheses. And if the function expects an argument, you need to pass that too. So in your case: `username(usernames)`

Answer (score 1):

`usernames` is defined as a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html) of 4 items, with the names `BTP`, `btp`, `Btp`, and `BTp`. You said "list" in your title but your code has no actual lists. Lists use brackets, tuples use parentheses.

Anyway, I'm assuming you actually want to check if the user's input actually was equal to the letters `"btp"` and you want the check to be case-insensitive, hence why you included all combos of uppercase and lowercase.

The main issue is that you didn't put quotes around the strings, so you have just 4 bare names sitting in your code which the interpreter expects to have been defined previously. But, you actually don't have to define all the possible combinations of uppercase and lowercase in the first place - there's a much easier method to do a case-insensitive string compare, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison).

So, your code just needs to look like:

```
usename = "btp"
def username(usernames2):
    if input('whats your username? : ').lower() == username
```

Or, if you want to check against multiple usernames, you can use the `in` operator:

```
usenames = ["btp", "abc", "foo", "bar"]
def username(usernames2):
    if input('whats your username? : ').lower() in usernames
```