# Create a conversation that has a Y/N answer

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to create a small bit of code in Python that runs a conversation, then asks a Y/N question i.e "Do you believe the sky is blue?"

When I run the code, it works well until I reach the question. It ignores my parameters for Y/N answers to print specific responses. It gives me the print response attached to my "else" statement.

I am confused if I am writing my If/elif/else statements wrong?

My code is written as follows:

```
x = input('do you believe the sky is blue')
if x == "yes":
   print("I believe you are correct")
elif x == "no":
   print('I think you have a unique perspective.')
else:
   print('Please answer Yes or No.)
```

Comment: If you are typing in "Yes" or "No", then your if and your elif statements will not hit, because they are case sensitive.

Comment: Check how I just changed the code formatting -- and try to do it that way yourself in the future.

Comment: \`\`\` marks the beginning of a code block, do the same to finish the code block.

Comment: As for the question, though, because you aren't showing us what input you type when running your program we can't speak to its behavior.

Comment: What are you actually typing as the answer?

Comment: @DaviASampaio, why the proposed edit to switch from three-backtick blocks to four-space-indents?

Comment: @Superhots, ...if the problem is that you're entering `Yes` but your program accepts only `yes`, that would make the question a duplicate of [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I made this change before (probably at the same time) the three-backtick edit. No need to change it.

Answer (score -1):

You use `.lower()` to obtain a lower case version of a string, and you are missing a `'` in the last `print()`:

```
x = input('do you believe the sky is blue ').lower()
if x == "yes":
   print("I believe you are correct")
elif x == "no":
   print('I think you have a unique perspective.')
else:
   print('Please answer Yes or No.')
```

Comment: If this is the problem, the question should be closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison (or one of the many others on the topic), not answered. In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point therein regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't look at the initial version but it's probably significant white space, typo, and case sensitive string compare.

Comment: Likely. Typo-based questions shouldn't be answered either, though, per #2 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and the bullet point in "How to Answer" that references the on-topic page.