# Data Structure and Algorithms using Python

Tags: python

The strings may have any casing. Rock, ROCK, roCK are all possible and valid.
Anyone can help on how to allow my code to accept any case like rOcK and all... ?

```
player1 = input('Enter rock/paper/scissors: ')
player2 = input('Enter rock/paper/scissors: ')

if (player1 == player2):
    print("The game is a Tie")
elif (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'scissors'):
    print("player 1 wins")
elif (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'paper'):
    print("player 2 wins")
elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'rock'):
    print("player 1 wins")
elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'scissors'):
    print("player 2 wins")
elif (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'paper'):
    print("player 1 wins")
elif (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'rock'):
    print("player 2 wins")
else:
    print("Invalid input")
```

My code is perfectly running just can't figure out how to code to allow it accept any case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accept the inputs in any case and convert both inputs to same case before writing the conditions like this:

```
player1 = input('Enter rock/paper/scissors: ') 
player2 = input('Enter rock/paper/scissors: ')
player1 = player1.lower()
player2 = player2.lower()

# then continue with if cases
```

Comment: you can upvote or mark it as accepted solution in case it helped you :)

Comment: Note, that `str.lower` works here, but is not the general way for caseless comparison of strings. This is what `str.casefold` is made for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.lower()` or `string.upper()` in Python, which converts the string to lower/upper case letters. This way you can have your string all upper or all lower, whichever you want.

f.e: if `player1='ROCK'` and you compare by `player1.lower()`, your `player1` will be evaluated as `rock` instead of `ROCK`

`string.lower()` documentation:

> The lower() method converts all uppercase characters in a string into lowercase characters and returns it.