# input give me incorrect even im writing correct answer

Tags: python, user-input

I'm trying to make quiz game but if i answered correct answer it gives me incorrect , is it case sensitive ?

Code :

```py
score = 0
question_n = 0

playing = input('Do you wish to start? (Yes-No)')
if playing == "yes" or playing == "y":
    question_n +=1
    ques = input(f'\n{question_n}. Who owns amazon? ')

    if ques == 'Jeff bezos':
        print('Correct! You got 1 point.')
        score +=1
        print(f'Your score is : {score}')
                 

    else:
        print('Incorrect')
        print(f'The correct answer is --> Jeff bezos. ')
        x = input('Press any key to exit..')
elif playing == "no" or playing == "n":
    print('Thanks for trying me (:')
```

Error :

```
Do you wish to start? (Yes-No)yes

1. Who owns amazon? jeff bezos
Incorrect
The correct answer is --> Jeff bezos. 
Press any key to exit..
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a `tkinter` question

Comment: Yes it's case sensitive. taking some string `s = 'jEfF bEzOs'` and setting `s = s.title()` will set `s = 'Jeff Bezos'` by capitalizing the first letter of every word in your string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, comparison of strings is case-sensitive. You could make it case-insensitive by performing the same case modification on both the input string and the comparison string, e.g.:

```py
if ques.upper() == 'Jeff bezos'.upper():
    ...
```

In the example above, both the user input and the "correct" string are converted to uppercase before comparison. This way, if the user inputs `"JeFf BeZoS"` and the correct answer is `"Jeff bezos"`, they are both compared as `"JEFF BEZOS"` and therefore considered equal.

There are functions for working with string cases in Python

- `str.upper()  # convert to upper case`
- `str.lower()  # convert to lower case`
- `str.capitalize()  # capitalize string`
- `str.title()  # capitalize every word in the string` (thanks @Vin, I was unaware of this one!)

##### Examples:

```
string = 'foo'
print(string.upper())
>>> FOO
```

```
string = 'FOO'
print(string.lower())
>>> foo
```

```
string = 'foo bar'
print(string.capitalize())
>>> Foo bar
```

```
string = 'foo bar'
print(string.title())
>>> Foo Bar
```

Comment: And there's [`casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold), which [can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29247821/15032126) with names like Gauß :)

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly That's cool! Man, I learn something new every day around here. Thanks for the info!