# Python: Simple calculator only return Addition function, won't return values for other specified functions

Tags: python

I'm very fresh to Python and am coding a simple text-based calculator that takes choice input and performs a simple arithmetic process depending on the input. My issue arises in this; regardless of whether I input 'Multiply' or 'Divide', the program is always returning to value of the addition function. Any ideas?

```
def main():
    whichCalc()
    print(finalNum)

def whichCalc():
    choice = input("Please enter one of the following; "
                   "Add, Multiply or Divide: ")
    if choice == 'Add' or 'add' or 'ADD':
        addNum()
    elif choice == 'Multiply' or 'multiply' or 'MULTIPLY':
        multNum()
    elif choice == 'Divide' or 'divide' or 'DIVIDE':
        divNum()
    else:
        print('What?')

def addNum():
    global finalNum
    finalNum = (firstNum + secondNum)
    return finalNum

def multNum():
    global finalNum
    finalNum = (firstNum * secondNum)
    return finalNum

def divNum():
    global finalNum
    finalNum = (firstNum / secondNum)
    return finalNum

firstNum = int(input('Enter the first number: '))
secondNum = int(input('Enter the second number: '))

main()
```

I've tried removing the 'or' syntax as well as shifting things around, I'm not sure as to why it's diehard on only using the 'addNum' function even when I'm not calling it.

Comment: Can be simplified as `if choice.lower() == 'add':`.  The `or` statement is not working as you’re expecting, and always evaluating to `True`, given the rule of ‘Truthiness’; if you’d like to do further research on the subject.

Comment: Thank you! I don't think I quite fully understand why the 'or' statement isn't working but I will follow up with research.

Comment: Your statement is parsed as `if (choice == 'Add')  or  ('add')  or  ('ADD'):`.  The string `'add'` always has a True value, so the first choice is always taken.  It has to be written `if choice == 'Add' or choice == 'add' or choice == 'ADD':`., or even `if choice in ('Add','add','ADD'):`, but the `.lower` option is smarter here.

Comment: Since you're trying to do a _case-insensitive_ comparison, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/319426/843953

Answer (score 1):

When using non-booleans in an if statement, python can act a bit strange if you're not used to it. Let's illustrate this with a code example.

For strings, any empty string (`""`) will evaluate to `False`, and any non-empty string will evaluate to `True`.

```
def is_string_empty(our_string):
    if our_string:
        print(f"No, {our_string} is not empty")
    else:
        print(f"Yes, {our_string} is empty")

is_string_empty("")
is_string_empty("some string")
```

Now that we understand this, let's look at the syntax error your code example is making. Specifically, let's focus on this line:

```
   if choice == 'Add' or 'add' or 'ADD':
```

You have three boolean expressions here. First, `choice == 'Add'`, which will work as you intended; it will evaluate to `True` if `choice` is `'Add'`. However, your mistake comes from the next two boolean expression: `'add'`, when evaluated as a boolean, is `True`, since it's not empty! Same for evaluation `'ADD'`; it will always be `True`. Since those are being `or`'d with `choice == 'Add'`, this if statement will *always* evaluate to True, so it will execute `addNum()` no matter the input!

This statement should be rewritten as:

```
   if choice == 'Add' or choice == 'add' or choice == 'ADD':
```

One last tip: instead of having these `or`s, you can use the `lower()` method of strings:

```
   if choice.lower() == 'add':
```

This will work for add, adD, aDd, Add, aDd, AdD, etc.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help

```py
def main():
    whichCalc()

def whichCalc():
    choice = input("Please enter one of the following; "
                   "Add, Multiply or Divide: ")
    if choice == 'Add' or choice =='add' or choice =='ADD':
        print(addNum())
    elif choice == 'Multiply' or choice =='multiply' or choice =='MULTIPLY':
        print(multNum())
    elif choice == 'Divide' or choice =='divide' or choice =='DIVIDE':
        print(divNum())
    else:
        print('What?')

def addNum():
    finalNum = (firstNum + secondNum)
    return finalNum

def multNum():
    finalNum = (firstNum * secondNum)
    return finalNum

def divNum():
    finalNum = (firstNum / secondNum)
    return finalNum

firstNum = int(input('Enter the first number: '))
secondNum = int(input('Enter the second number: '))

main()
```

you do not need global keyword because you are not going to change the value of the global variable

the functions return values then you can put the function inside print() directly

your problem was in this section :

```py
if choice == 'Add' or 'add' or 'ADD':
    print(addNum())
elif choice == 'Multiply' or 'multiply' or 'MULTIPLY':
    print(multNum())
elif choice == 'Divide' or 'divide' or 'DIVIDE':
    print(divNum())
else:
    print('What?')
```

because you can not say

> if thing == value1 or value2 or value3

Comment: Tip: Use `.lower()` and simplify the `if` statements.  Or pop the functions into a `dict` and call accordingly.

Comment: yes , you are right, but this thing is advanced he is a new to python. 

thanks

Comment: The `dict` option, perhaps.  But the `.lower()` approach is an excellent education opportunity, providing it’s explained clearly in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Non empty strings are evaluated as True while empty strings are Falsy. The **or** operator calls the **__or__** method which returns the first true item. Calling **or** on a bunch of strings will returns the first non-empty string. The **and** operator returns the first falsy item in the chain.

Normally all-caps are used to indicate constants in python. Also try not to use global variables unless necessary. For specifying behavior, being the mathematical operator, pass in everything the function needs to operate. Then the function is only specifying behavior and is getting its arguments from the call arguments and not breaking scopes.

Also using a dictionary is good for mapping keys to values. In Python, functions are objects, so they can be passed around. This is why I stored the three supported functions in the dictionary. The operator is then pulled out and the called on the two numbers.

The dict.setdefault(key, value_if_key_is_missing) method is a one time use method for safely looking up a key in a dictionary. If the key is not found, the default is returned. This does not change the dictionary in any way.

A lambda function is a more semi-advanced function that is just a one-liner function. Normally you don't want to store lambda functions because that can introduce unexpected errors, but ours are okay.

```
OPS = {'ADD': lambda x, y: x + y,
       'MULTIPLY': lambda x, y: x * y,
       'DIVIDE': lambda x, y: x / y}


def which_calc(x, y, operator):
    default_response = lambda *_: print('What?')
    operator = OPS.setdefault(operator.upper(), default_rsponse)
    return operator(x, y)


def main():
    x = int(input('Enter the first number: '))
    print(x)

    y = int(input('Enter the second number: '))
    print(y)

    choice = input("Please enter one of the following; "
                   "Add, Multiply or Divide: ")
    print(which_calc(x, y, choice))
main()
```